# How to run regular google maps on android go?

Tags: google-play-store, google-maps, android-go

I'm trying to install the regular heavy version android google maps from play store but it only brings up google maps go. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: You can install it by downloading the APK file of the app from any site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can download it here from apkmirror

https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/maps/maps-10-14-1-release/